# Use United Airlines travel certificate for another passenger?

Tags: tickets, united-airlines, vouchers

When I look at changing a flight to a cheaper flight, I see that I'll be issued a "United Airlines Travel Certificate" (for the difference in cost, minus the change fee).

Can that credit then be used to buy a ticket for another passenger, or only me?

Comment: What do the Terms and Conditions of the certificate say? Do they say that it is transferable?

Comment: The thing is that United has different types of "certicates". Depending on the  ticket class, some of these may be usable for different persons, some may not. Also, they can change their habits at any point in time. A few years ago, certificates given out after customer complaints *could* be used for other persons (just to add the first "data point" in this thread).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I ended up going to the source, [tweeting United Airlines directly](https://twitter.com/marksmayo/status/642194221563183104).

They've just [replied](https://twitter.com/united/status/642249170007523328), saying that YES, they are transferable, and provided a [link with more information](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/content/booking/flight/offerCode.aspx):

The link is basically instructions on use of one of these certificates, and from those instructions it's merely a code, so not bound to any particular passenger.

Comment: Don't see anything on that link about transferring it, but if they said yes, then that is that.  You can reward yourself your donated 50 points ;-)

Comment: @Tom alas I can't award it to myself, so I'll pass it on to you ;)

Answer (score 5):

United doesn't have a "one rule fits all" for certificates, so you need to check the rules for your specific one.  They are usually provided in the email about the eCertificate or printed on the back of a paper certificate.  United unfortunately does not provide terms on their website for certs.

The certificates in general are restricted to airfare only, can't be applied towards extra fees like baggage or enhanced seats.  But in years past (it has been a while since I had a UA cert) you could apply it to someone else's airfare if they were traveling with you on the same flights.